# Statistical comparison between two stochastic algorithms

Tags: confidence-interval, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, reliability, method-comparison

I am working on a mechanics problem with variability in material properties. For that I need to analyze the efficiency of two methods for same accuracy (confidence level I guess?), the first one being direct Monte Carlo and the second one being a hybrid method between Monte Carlo and an intrusive method.

How should I approach this? How to calculate the number of samples I should take? Which statistics should I compare?

Please site any possible reference for your answer.